# Where can I find the music of the trop for Book of Ruth

Tags: product-recommendation, trop-cantillation, book-of-ruth

I need to find out the trop for the book of Ruth fairly soon because our Rabbi has developed a minor illness and I'll have to do the reading on Shavuot.  Surely there is something on the web with the melody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Dr. Shmuel in a comment, here are two recordings using the traditional Ashkenazi melody:

[Modern Hebrew pronunciation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACRhKtO9d1Y) - Cantor Moshe P. Weisblum, PhD

Ashkenazi pronunciation [Part I](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707968/rabbi-jeremy-wieder/megillot/ruth/ruth1/) [Part II](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707969/rabbi-jeremy-wieder/megillot/ruth/ruth2/) [Part III](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707970/rabbi-jeremy-wieder/megillot-ruth-ruth3/) [Part IV](https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/707971/rabbi-jeremy-wieder/megillot-ruth-ruth4/) - Rabbi Jeremy Wieder